# How to make a plot with data? (Plotly preferably)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot, plotly

I have a dataset and a piece of it looks like that:

|  | Metrics | 01.08.21 | 01.09.21 | 01.10.21 | 01.11.21 | 01.12.21 | 01.13.21 | 01.14.21 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Events | NaN | NaN | NaN | Sales | NaN | Table sales | Pillow Sales |
| 1 | The price of pillows | NaN | NaN | 1.9473 | 1.832 | 2.13 | 2.20 | 3 |
| 2 | The price of tables | 1.19 | NaN | NaN | 1.9 | 2.0 | 2.0 | 2.5 |

I need to make a plot "Price of the pillows vs Date", but if there was an event on the date it must be on the plot. How can I add information about events and make a plot?

For simple plot I tried (with Plotly)

```
df = df.T
fig = px.line(df, x = df.index, y = df['The price of pillows'], width=900, height=800)
fig.update_layout(title="The price of pillows trend",xaxis_title="Date", yaxis_title="Price"
fig.show()
```

But something is wrong :(

Final result have to be like this pic:
[image]

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I fixed your table. The problem with it was that you needed to put an empty line before it for some reason. :)

Comment: Hi @AnnaShevtsova welcome on SO. It will be great if you can have a look at [ask] and then try to produce a [mcve]. i.e you can justa share a sample of your `df` copying and pasting the output of `df.head(10).to_dict()`.

Comment: @rpanai I only fixed the display of the OP's table in the question. I didn't actually solve their problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for error in plotting is due to the mismatch in column assignment after doing a transpose of the dataFrame with `df.T`

This can be solved using `df.set_index()` method.

original `df`:

|  | **Metrics** | **01.08.21** | **1.09.21** | **01.10.21** | **01.11.21** | **01.12.21** | **01.13.21** | **01.14.21** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **0** | Events | NaN | NaN | NaN | Sales | NaN | Table sales | Pillow Sales |
| **1** | The price of pillows | NaN | NaN | 1.9473 | 1.832 | 2.13 | 2.2 | 3 |
| **2** | The price of tables | 1.19 | NaN | NaN | 1.9 | 2.00 | 2 | 2.5 |

`df.T` (notice that column names are now indices of df):

|  | **0** | **1** | **2** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Metrics | Events | The price of pillows | The price of tables |
| 01.08.21 | NaN | NaN | 1.19 |
| 1.09.21 | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 01.10.21 | NaN | 1.9473 | NaN |
| 01.11.21 | Sales | 1.832 | 1.9 |
| 01.12.21 | NaN | 2.13 | 2 |
| 01.13.21 | Table sales | 2.2 | 2 |
| 01.14.21 | Pillow Sales | 3 | 2.5 |

Hence, we do:

```
df.set_index('Metrics',inplace=True)
df = df.T
```

So now, `df` is:

| **Metrics** | **Events** | **The price of pillows** | **The price of tables** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01.08.21 | NaN | NaN | 1.19 |
| 1.09.21 | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 01.10.21 | NaN | 1.9473 | NaN |
| 01.11.21 | Sales | 1.832 | 1.9 |
| 01.12.21 | NaN | 2.13 | 2 |
| 01.13.21 | Table sales | 2.2 | 2 |
| 01.14.21 | Pillow Sales | 3 | 2.5 |

And, finally we can proceed with plotting. the `Events` column can be annotated on the graph using the `text` keyword argument for `px.line`

Full code for plotting:

```
df.set_index('Metrics',inplace=True)
df = df.T
fig = px.line(df, x = df.index, y = "The price of pillows", text="Events", width=900, height=800)
fig.update_traces(textposition='bottom right')
fig.update_layout(title="The price of pillows trend",xaxis_title="Date", yaxis_title="Price")
fig.show()
```

**Output figure:**

[image: Required Figure]